# Can I get Item Quantity from an ebay API FindItems call?

Tags: xml, ebay-api

If I enter my appid, a keyword, and an ebay sellerID into the url below, it will search their store and return information about items it finds in XML format.  It doesn't seem to return the Quantity available for the items though.  Is it possible to get that data in this call, or do I have to do a completely seperate getSingleItem call to get that information?  I was hoping to get all the data I need in one call.  Thanks.

http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SECURITY-APPNAME=MyAppID&keywords=MyKeyword&itemFilter.name=Seller&itemFilter.value=SellersEbayId

Answer (score 1):

unfortunadly quantity cant be retrieved within this call (findItemByKeywords) you can have a look at the outputSelectors for this API / Call on the ebay docs: http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/finding/CallRef/findItemsByKeywords.html#Request.outputSelector

i thought the findItemsAdvanced call would be able to provide this information but if the docs are right it shares the outputSelector with the findItemByKeyword (maybe worth a try to see if the ebay docs are wrong on this call)

as plan b:

if you are searching via keyword only, you will need to retrieve more detailed information for each item via a separeted call, to reduce the amount of calls you could use the getMultipleItem Call have build you a ready to test example here: https://ebay-sdk.intradesys.com/s/72b32a1f754ba1c09b3695e0cb6cde7f

xml would look like:

```
<GetMultipleItemsRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <ItemID>301422884035</ItemID>
    <ItemID>141488562471</ItemID>
    <ItemID>231408359451</ItemID>
    <IncludeSelector>Details</IncludeSelector>
</GetMultipleItemsRequest>
```

response will contain multiple:

```
<Item>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
</Item>
```

tags

this call can take up to 20 item IDs so you could reduce the amount of calls

if you are searching for items from a specific seller you could use the getSellerList-Call